# How to dismiss notification on action click?

Tags: android

I want to dismiss my notification, when clicked on dismiss from the notification . Just like we dismiss it on swipe.

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("isFromBadge", false);

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(ctx, ResultActivity.class);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(ctx);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(ResultActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

  //  PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(ctx)
            .setContentTitle(
                    ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(message)
            .setWhen(when)
            .setStyle(new Notification.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(result))
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .addAction(R.drawable.bell, "Dismiss", resultPendingIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.bell, "Share", contentIntent)
            .setLargeIcon(result)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .build();
```

Answer (score 8):

Try like this

```
public void showNotification(Context ctx) {
    int noti_id = 100;
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent actionIntent = new Intent(ctx, ActionReceiver.class);
    actionIntent.putExtra("noti_id", noti_id);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, noti_id, actionIntent, 
        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(ctx)
                                .setContentTitle("hello")
                                .setContentText("Hello")
                                .addAction(R.drawable.bell, "dismiss", pendingIntent)
                                .setAutoCancel(false)
                                .build();


    notificationManager.notify(noti_id, notification);   
}



public class ActionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null) {
            int noti_id = intent.getIntExtra("noti_id", -1);

            if (noti_id > 0) {
                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                notificationManager.cancel(noti_id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work for multiple notifications, only for the latest one

Answer (score 0):

I had a same error.Finally I get the solution the problem is beacause the  reqeust code you write is same when you have numbers of PendingIntent. It make the one PendingIntent work but the others doesn't work and the click is unuse.
In my case ,just make the request code different ,and the problems solved.

Answer (score -1):

You can cancel notification using `notification_id` you provided while creating notification using `NotificationManager`

To notify -

```
mNotificationManager.notify(_notificationId /* ID of notification */, mBuilder.build());
```

To cancel notification -

```
mNotificationManager.cancel(_notificationId);
```

Comment: I want to cancel only when the user clicks on the dismiss button.

Comment: Where is dismiss button? Ge the click event and call `cancel` over there.

Comment: What is the purpose of `setAutoCancel(true)` then?